# How to send NRPN messages with pygame midi

Tags: python, pygame, midi

I'm writing a program that will read incoming cc messages from a device that can only send cc's and send it to another device as an nrpn message. I know how to send cc messages from pygame but I can't wrap my mind around how to send nrpn's. I looked at the Vriareon code and I don't see anywhere in there were it even accesses midi. Can anyone give an example of how this is done?

Thank you!

Comment: NRPNs *are* CCs.

Comment: Correct. The thing I don't understand is what number to use for the control message. If I have cc number 17 I could do something like this:"self.midi_out.write_short(0xb0, 17, 123)". How do I address the right NRPN when an NRPN looks like this "0:15"?

Answer (score 2):

NRPN messages *are* CC messages.

However, NRPN numbers are distinct from CC numbers. The [MIDI specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/the-midi-1-0-specification) says:

> Controller number 6 (Data Entry), in conjunction with Controller numbers 96 (Data Increment), 97 (Data Decrement), 98 (Non-Registered Parameter Number LSB), 99 (Non-Registered Parameter Number MSB), 100 (Registered Parameter Number LSB), and 101 (Registered Parameter Number MSB), extend the number of controllers available via MIDI. Parameter data is transferred by first selecting the parameter number to be edited using controllers 98 and 99 or 100 and 101, and then adjusting the data value for that parameter using controller number 6, 96, or 97.

To change a controller like volume (7), you would send a single message:

```
B0 07 xx
```

To change an NRPN, you would select the NRPN first:

```
B0 63 mm
B0 62 ll
```

And then change the currently selected NRPN with the data entry controller:

```
B0 06 mm
B0 26 ll  (optional, for 14-bit values)
```

So setting NRPN 0:1 to value 42 could be done with:

```
self.midi_out.write_short(0xb0, 0x63, 0)
self.midi_out.write_short(0xb0, 0x62, 1)
self.midi_out.write_short(0xb0, 0x06, 42)
```

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer! Sorry for not grasping this. When I send a cc message I use one number for the cc and one for it's value and I can do that using pygame's write_short method. What would an NRPN change message look like in pygame code? Would I use pygame's write() method and include all these values in an array of messages?

Comment: Those are the bytes that you would send.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm having a hard time understanding this. I don't get how this would look in code. Maybe if I could see an example of that it would make more sense to me. I'm working from a data chart that presents the nrpns in this format "env 2 attack,  NRPN - 0:1,  0 – 127". I don't know how the notation "0:1" translates to any information I've read on NRPNs. The other thing is, when I use the write_short() method I send it 3 parameters. It seems though that an nrpn message would require several more parameters and I don't know what it all should look like.

Comment: I just saw your code example. Makes total sense now! Thank you!